# In Blackberry 10 Cascades is there a way to change the shape of an image or imageButton in blackberry cascades using an image mask or alpha channel?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

In Blackberry 10 Cascades (C++, QT, QML) is there a way to change the shape of an image or imageButton in Blackberry 10 Cascades using an image mask or alpha channel or a masking colour (such as magic pink) - so that images and imageButtons don't have to be in the shape of a rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no such limitations in the SDK. The `ImageButton` class provides methods for setting and resetting its images so it will be looking like the actual images you supply for it.

There's a good example of this right in the [official ImageButton documentation.](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__imagebutton.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9-slice images to make custom shaped buttons.  Basically create an image with rounded corners or custom shape and then using 9-slice it will scale correctly.

This blog post by Blackberry should help you get started:
http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/08/cascades-framework-9-slicing/

For a basic example, create your image (myImage.png) and then create a new text file with same name but ending in .amd. (myImage.amd)

Then paste the following into the .amd file (adjust values as needed):

```
#RimCascadesAssetMetaData version=1.0
sliceMargins: 15 15 15 15
source: "myImage.png"
```